# jQuery Not Working, "Zentabs" conflict?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a jQuery plugin(?)/library called "Zentabs" and for some reason it's preventing any other jQuery code I write from working...this isn't the first time I've had trouble with jQuery library's breaking other pieces of code but usually I can rearange where the code appears and that'll usually fix whatever the problem is but this time nothing's working -_-

This is what I've got in the header;

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

alert("WTF!!!!!");

});

</script>
<script src="<?php baseURL();?>/zentabs.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="<?php baseURL();?>/date_time.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.lazyload.js?v=4" type="text/javascript"   charset="utf-8"></script>
```

When I remove

```
<script src="<?php baseURL();?>/zentabs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then

```
$(document).ready(function() {

alert("WTF!!!!!");

});

</script>
```

Work just fine, but when I include zentabs.js, nothing works =/

And here's the zentabs.js file > http://zenverse.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/zentabs.js

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

P.S. I'm so freakin' frustrated right now I'm about ready to jump off
   a building -_-

Comment: hey, I tried your code and remove date_time.js, so its work fine,
can you give me actual path of date_time.js, so I will check again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need noConflict there. Try this, then from then forward just use jQuery instead of $()

```
$.noConflict();    

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  alert("WTF!!!!!");
});
```

You could also set jQuery to a variable if you want, so its a bit shorter to type on all your calls later.

```
 var jq = jQuery;
 jq(document).ready(function() {
  alert("WTF!!!!!");

  jq('input').val( '...' );
});
```

Read more about noConflict on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: Okay guys, Ty so much for your suggestions - really helped lead me down the right road :) I've wasted soo much freakin' time on this stupid thing. So, after trying my own code by itself and then with jQuery.noConflict(); I found with jQuery.noConflict(); it wouldn't work.. then I looked through zentabs.js and found $zentabs = jQuery.noConflict(); replaced every instance of $zentabs with just $ and removed $zentabs = jQuery.noConflict(); and now everything works perfectly! it seems jQuery.noConflict(); itself was the problem, Weird huh? Anyway Thanks again 4 the help! Much appreciated! :)

Comment: You're welcome Jordan :) Just stay calm and if ever you're stuck on a problem, get some coffee/break and come back later to solve em. it helps

Answer (score 1):

try this if this solves:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.noConflict();

    alert("WTF!!!!!");

});
```

your can find documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/